# is that available save a data at the localstorage or cookie in liquid with shopify?

Tags: cookies, local-storage, shopify, liquid

i want to save some data at the localstorage or cookie

i know that how to save data with javascript not liquid

i found some answer at the shopify that this isn't available

Is there any other way?

Save data at the browser's localstorage or cookie with liquid language

Comment: the liquid is a server-side language and is parsed to HTML on the server, local-stogare and cookie are workes on the browser, and with javascript, you interact with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript in your .liquid theme files included in a script tag or create a JS file and include it:

**Inline HTML Javascript (layout/templates/sections/snippet files):**

```
<script>
localStorage.setItem('namespace', 'value')
</script>
```

**JS file (in your assets folder)**

```
// my-file.js
localStorage.setItem('namespace', 'value')
```

this would require you to include the asset in the relevant liquid file:

```
{{ 'my-file.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```